# Loop function for vector of character strings in R

Tags: r, loops, plot

I need to loop the following function to output separate plots for all values in a vector of character strings. These values are three letter country codes, with the example of the single Tanzania (`"TZA"`) shown below. The vector of country codes can be specified by `CountryList$Country`

```
 tiff("TZA_vanda.tiff", units="in", width=8, height= 6, res=120)
    tscsPlot(a.out2, cs = "TZA", var = "vanda")
    dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, obviously, but perhaps something along these lines?

```
for (i in unique(CountryList$Country)) {
  tiff(sprintf("%s_vanda.tiff", i), units="in", width=8, height= 6, res=120)
  tscsPlot(a.out2, cs = i, var = "vanda")
  dev.off()
}
```